# Air Pollution Egg - XML feeds from Cosm

Tags: xml, feed, sensors, cosm

I have been trying to create an application using Cosm's XML feed, and I would like to know if (and how) it is possible to retrieve a XML between a specified limit of time (for example, to a CO sensor, a dataset containing the data of 30 days divided by days).

Just to facilitate, the feed I have been trying to use is: https://cosm.com/feeds/115590.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs you can specify the start and end or a duration and get back a sampling of the data:

http://cosm.com/docs/v2/history.html

e.g. https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/115590?duration=1hour&interval=0

will give you the raw data for the last hour